# Ubuntu 22.04 ethernet stop to function out of a sudden

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, ethernet

For three days my Ubuntu 22.04 installation behaves strangely. The laptop starts fine. After a few hours I see a high load. I do not know if this is related, nor I could see any process which is responsible, the load is only for a few seconds.

A few hours after booting the computer the Ethernet interface seems to be completely inactive. I still can use WiFi without any problem.

When I try to ping my router internally or 8.8.8.8 I get the message that the network is not reachable. When I switch on WiFi all is fine.

Other Laptops in the same net do not have this problem.

Changing the Ethernet cable from a docking to directly to the laptop and reverse does not make a change.

Rebooting the laptop does not change the behavior.

Yesterday and the day before the laptop just started to work again after running for a few hours on WiFi. Only to repeat the story today.

This is so strange. Can someone help me to narrow down the source of the problem down and hopefully fix it?

**Update 6 hours later**
The laptop was not rebooted, I just gave it a try to connect via ethernet and it works. Unfortunately I am pretty sure that it will drop again.
Anyone who has an idea what could cause this behavior? Or what to do to find the source of this problem?

One fear I have is that something temporarily happens on my router (a Fritzbox 7590) blocking only my laptop. The logs on the router are not very verbose.. There is nothing suspicious I can see...

**Update one day later**
The story started and ended as it did the last three days. Hope anyone has an idea how to track that down.

Thanks a lot
Michael

This is the syslog when I try to activate the not working Ethernet connection:

```
Oct 14 11:45:30 LU30 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 14 11:45:39 LU30 dbus-daemon[9448]: [session uid=1000 pid=9448] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Extract' unit='tracker-extract-3.service' requested by ':1.8' (uid=1000 pid=9504 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3 " label="unconfined")
Oct 14 11:45:39 LU30 systemd[9424]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
Oct 14 11:45:39 LU30 dbus-daemon[9448]: [session uid=1000 pid=9448] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Extract'
Oct 14 11:45:39 LU30 systemd[9424]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Oct 14 11:45:59 LU30 dbus-daemon[9448]: [session uid=1000 pid=9448] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Extract' unit='tracker-extract-3.service' requested by ':1.8' (uid=1000 pid=9504 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3 " label="unconfined")
Oct 14 11:45:59 LU30 systemd[9424]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
Oct 14 11:45:59 LU30 dbus-daemon[9448]: [session uid=1000 pid=9448] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Extract'
Oct 14 11:45:59 LU30 systemd[9424]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Oct 14 11:46:04 LU30 goa-daemon[9566]: goa_http_client_check() failed: 2 — Fehler beim Auflösen von »akazia.dedyn.io«: Temporärer Fehler bei der Namensauflösung
Oct 14 11:46:13 LU30 NetworkManager[1481]: <info>  [1665740773.0943] device (enp0s31f6): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 14 11:46:13 LU30 NetworkManager[1481]: <info>  [1665740773.0956] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct 14 11:46:13 LU30 NetworkManager[1481]: <warn>  [1665740773.0963] device (enp0s31f6): Activation: failed for connection 'HRHOME'
Oct 14 11:46:13 LU30 NetworkManager[1481]: <info>  [1665740773.0971] device (enp0s31f6): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 14 11:46:13 LU30 NetworkManager[1481]: <info>  [1665740773.1143] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): canceled DHCP transaction
Oct 14 11:46:13 LU30 NetworkManager[1481]: <info>  [1665740773.1164] policy: auto-activating connection 'HRHOME' (bcba6a57-d428-4181-99a6-3b27b20e9132)
Oct 14 11:46:13 LU30 NetworkManager[1481]: <info>  [1665740773.1176] device (enp0s31f6): Activation: starting connection 'HRHOME' (bcba6a57-d428-4181-99a6-3b27b20e9132)
Oct 14 11:46:13 LU30 NetworkManager[1481]: <info>  [1665740773.1178] device (enp0s31f6): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 14 11:46:13 LU30 NetworkManager[1481]: <info>  [1665740773.1185] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Oct 14 11:46:13 LU30 NetworkManager[1481]: <info>  [1665740773.1189] device (enp0s31f6): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 14 11:46:13 LU30 NetworkManager[1481]: <info>  [1665740773.1202] device (enp0s31f6): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 14 11:46:13 LU30 NetworkManager[1481]: <info>  [1665740773.1206] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
```